# JS async await "nothing" in Node?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a method like this:

```
    private async sendToAll(clients) {
        for(const client of clients) {
            this.send(client, message);
            await true; // What do to put here to make rest of app execute?
        }
    }
```

It is a method which loops through a large array doing a process. What I would like to do is make it so after each iteration of the loop, the rest of the application runs through a cycle. I would image I just put 'await' and then it would do as expected. But that doesn't work. 'await true' doesn't work either.

Unity C# uses this technique a lot with coroutines. The command you use is 'yield return null', basically pauses the executing of a async method, lets the main thread run a cycle through the rest of the app, then comes back to the async method where it left off.

How do I do this in js?

Comment: `this.send()` is a synchronous method? Then make it asynchronous.

Comment: See also [Await nothing? Using an empty await to break up a large synchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57300969/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

If `this.send` is an asynchronous method returning a promise, you should put the `await` in front of the method call, like this:

```js
private async sendToAll(clients) {
    for(const client of clients) {
        await this.send(client, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give you app a breath while some expensive operations you can send next loop iteration to the macrotasks queue (setTimeout with 0 delay, for example) or to the microtasks queue using queueMicrotask(). This will let other sync operations in the call stack to be done.

Comment: `queueMicrotask` will achieve nothing that a plain `await;` would not as well. And it actually would block the application.